# How to optimize joins between pyspark dataframes using different, multiple join keys?

Tags: apache-spark, join, pyspark

General join optimization techniques mostly apply either for joins between tables that share the same join key which makes it possible to use the same partition for multiple tables and joins.

However, assume I have multiple large tables containing terabytes of data for which broadcast joins won't work. Each table has different join keys to other tables, and some tables must be joined on two keys. For example, table A is joined to table B using join key (ab). Table B is joined to table C using join keys (bc1, bc2). How can I optimize the join between tables A and C, given that each join uses different keys?

I've already tried:

1. Using the same partitioner for all 3 tables. These tables do have one column in common, so I have partitioned this column. However I'm not sure if this actually optimizes the joins as this column is not the join key.
2. Using a two-pass method proposed in other posts. It's much faster than (1) but I would like to improve this method as this relies on a single partition column across all tables.

Comment: can you further explain why you need to optimize the joins ? are you having some issues ? are you having skews in your data ? have you tried to count differents join keys in each dataframe, do you tried repartitioning the data in the join columns ?

Comment: Do a regular, "naive" join and add the query plan to your question. Describe what steps you think are sub optimal.